# How to run an APP from within my project folder?

Tags: applescript

I would like to know how to run an application that is inside the folder of my project,
I've tried something like:

```
set myApp to quoted form of (POSIX path of (path to resource "blabla.app"))
            tell application "Finder" to open & myApp
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to treat various commands like shell scripts, so you are running into a couple of issues.

- The `path to` commands return aliases.  The Finder doesn’t know about
  POSIX paths, but it does know aliases, so you don’t need to do stuff like
  coerce or quote the path.
- The Finder’s `open` command takes a file reference as a parameter,
  while `&` is a concatenation operator, so your snippet should be
  something like:

  ```
  set myApp to path to resource "blabla.app"
  tell application "Finder" to open myApp
  ```

Comment: Woww, thanks, working like a charm, thanks for your explanation.

Comment: Error: Finder got an error: Handler can’t handle objects of this class.